# What needs to be in my Java keystore?

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, keystore, certificate-store

I'm coming from a pure Windows/IIS environment.  That's all I know, and that just barely.  I have a wildcard certificate that I purchased from GeoTrust that I want to apply to a site that runs on Java/Tomcat.  Apparently I'm supposed to create a Java keystore.  I have successfully converted an exported PFX file to a Java keystore in the past, and it worked, but I didn't really understand what I was doing.  I took the contents of the encrypted PFX file (using OpenSSL) and separated it out into multiple unencrypted .pem files, deleted their headers, converted them to .der files, and put them (only what I determined to be the private key and the root certificate) into a .jks Java keystore.

This seemed to work back when I used it, but now I need to re-implement it, and I want to understand what's going on:
Do I need the CA certs?
If so, should they be separate or together (I think there are two)?
Do I need the Root cert?
What is the deal with aliases?
Are both my private key and the entire keystore itself password protected?

That's how little I know.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need the private key and the entire certificate chain.